# Jquery getJson issue to simplify the answer

Tags: php, jquery

I have this Object:

```
{"15":{"id":15,"name":"Termostato","wiring_pi_pin":11,"is_local":0}}
```

Object come from this selfwritten API

```
foreach ($gpio as $object) {
    $temp['id'] = $object->id;
    $temp['name'] = $object->name;
    $temp['wiring_pi_pin'] = $object->wiring_pi_pin;
    $temp['is_local'] = $object->is_local;

    $api[$object->id] = $temp;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($api);
```

and I read it (I need key and value) with this code:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(key,value) {
        $.each(value, function(subkey,subvalue) {
            console.log(subkey +' is ' + subvalue);
        });
    });
});
```

Is it possible to simplify in PHP and Or in JS?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why not just `echo json_encode($gpio);`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to convert the objects to associative arrays, since JSON represents them both the same way. So the only thing you really need to do is create a top-level associative array that uses `$object->id` as the keys.

```
foreach ($gpio as $object) {
    $api[$object->id] = $object;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($api);
```